# reverse auth token from server side with Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I saw that Twitter4j has interface to [oauth](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth)

Does it have an interface for reverse auth token as described [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth)?

This would require adding, among others:

```
 x_auth_mode reverse_auth
```

Answer (score -1):

See:
twitter4j.auth.OAuthSupport

`RequestToken getOAuthRequestToken(java.lang.String callbackURL,
                                java.lang.String xAuthAccessType,
                                java.lang.String xAuthMode)
                                  throws TwitterException`

Retrieves a request token

Parameters:
    `callbackURL` - callback URL
    `xAuthAccessType` - Overrides the access level an application requests to a users account. Supported values are read or write. This parameter is intended to allow a developer to register a read/write application but also request read only access when appropriate.
    `xAuthMode` - Set to reverse_auth to obtain a special request token to be used in the reverse auth process.
Returns:
    generated request token
Since:
    Twitter4J 2.2.3